# I found a working code to insert a node at a heap implemented in array in C++ and I wonder why does the code work despite incrementing the size array

Tags: c++, arrays, heap, insertion

The code I provided below is an implementation of inserting a node inside a heap (array). As to my knowledge, an array has its size defined during its initialization and can't be changed afterwards.
How does this code still works, when it increments the size of the array to insert the node?

Code:

```
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int arr[5] =  {10,5,3,2,4};
    int n = 5;
    int key = 200;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }

    insertNode(arr, n, key);
    cout << n << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}

void heapify(int heap[], int size, int i){
    int parent = (i-1)/2;
    if(parent >= 0){
        if(heap[parent] < heap[i]){
            swap(heap[parent], heap[i]);
            heapify(heap, size, parent);
        }
    }
}

void insertNode(int heap[], int &size, int key){
    size++;
    heap[size-1] = key;
    heapify(heap, size, size-1);
}
```

Output:

```
10 5 3 2 4 
6
200 5 10 2 4 3
```

I tried using this code at different C++ compilers and it still works

Comment: There's no rule in C++ that says bugged programs must not work. This program is accessing an array out of bounds, so that is a bug, but all that means is that the program has *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: 1. This code does not compile. Be kind to post a [mcve]. 2. Are you asking about why the code that is not shown is working?

Comment: The code has undefined behavior. That can fail in some visible way, but can also appear to work correctly, for some uncertain amount of time. In real life, it usually fails at the worst possible time, such as when giving a demo to a prospective investor.

Comment: You "found" code... The code shown is a hybrid between C++ and C and you can (must) throw it away. Using "C" style arrays (with undefined sizes) is good way to shoot yourself in the foot.  You should use std::vector (or std::array) and [std::make_heap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/make_heap) (the last link even has a correct example)

Comment: *I tried using this code at different C++ compilers and it still works* -- You didn't try Visual C++ 2022 using a debug build.  After adding the missing headers and other edits, your code stops dead with a `"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted."` error.